# Anyone know of any issues with using VS2010 with TFS 2005

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

We want to upgrade to VS2010 but are currently using TFS 2005. Does VS2010 integrate cleanly with the older versions of TFS. We're not upgrading to SQL Server 2008 anytime soon which is why we're still on TFS 2005.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the VS2010 RC with Team Foundation Server 2005 with no issues.

Everything worked as expected (but VS2010 will try to convert any older project/solution files as expected when you try to open them).